# How to merge 2 images alpha channels?

Tags: python, opencv

The brief of the task: I have 2 BGR images which I blend at specific point, for that moment I stuck with merging alpha channels at image ROI my result is on image (sorry for dimensions). As you can see around the image black part show but I want to make it transparent. [image]

My approach:

```
### Stuff for selecting image mask using hsv channels
...
...
...
### Apply the mask using the numpy arrays
    masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(frame_roi, frame_roi, mask=hsvThesholded) ### applying binary mask
    masked_img = cv2.cvtColor(masked_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
    # Extract alpha channel from masked image
    alpha_channel = masked_img[:, :, 3]
    # Normalize alpha channel from range [0, 255] to [0, 1]
    alpha_channel = alpha_channel.astype(float) / 255.0
    # Apply alpha blending to masked image
    masked_img = masked_img[:, :, :3] * alpha_channel[:, :, np.newaxis]
    # Overlay masked image onto background
    background[rectRoi[0]:rectRoi[1], rectRoi[2]:rectRoi[3], :] = masked_img + background[rectRoi[0]:rectRoi[1],
                                                                                rectRoi[2]:rectRoi[3], :] * (
                                                                                1- alpha_channel[:, :, np.newaxis])
```

Input data:

[image]

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

What should I mention to apply alpha channel to picture with the fastest performance (bruteforce option is not applicable)?
I am apologize for the inconvenience dimensions of the sample.

Comment: If you want to merge two images, please share your two images and some indication of the expected result.

Comment: Note: all proposed solutions (so far) treat the alpha channel, which *is not binary*, as a *binary mask*. edges will be either fully transparent or fully opaque. there will be no blending with the proposed solutions. a proper solution must involve multiplication, subtraction, addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution using the binary mask `hsvThresholded` (use my code styling suck).

````
   masked_img = cv2.cvtColor(masked_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

    # Extract alpha channel from masked image
    alpha_channel = hsvThesholded
    # Normalize alpha channel from range [0, 255] to [0, 1]
    alpha_channel = alpha_channel.astype(float) / 255.0
    # Apply alpha blending to masked image
    masked_img = masked_img[:, :, :3] * alpha_channel[:, :, np.newaxis]
    # Overlay masked image onto background
    background[rectRoi[0]:rectRoi[1], rectRoi[2]:rectRoi[3], :] = masked_img + background[rectRoi[0]:rectRoi[1],
                                                                                rectRoi[2]:rectRoi[3], :] * (
                                                                                1- alpha_channel[:, :, np.newaxis])
    # Convert background image back to BGR color space
    background = cv2.cvtColor(background, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)

```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the two input images and get their dimensions
- Create a black image the size of the background image, add an opaque alpha channel to it and insert the foreground image into its center
- Extract the base (bgr) image and alpha channel from the padded foreground image and convert the alpha channel to 3 channels
- Merge the two images bgr and img2 using the alpha channel as a mask
- Save the results

Foreground:

[image]

Background:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image with alpha
img1 = cv2.imread('face.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
h1, w1 = img1.shape[:2]

# read background image
img2 = cv2.imread('blue_rect.png')
h2, w2 = img2.shape[:2]

# create black image the size of img2, add opaque alpha then insert img1 inside it
img1_pad = np.zeros_like(img2)
img1_pad = cv2.cvtColor(img1_pad, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
yo = (h2-h1)//2
xo = (w2-w1)//2
img1_pad[yo:yo+h1, xo:xo+w1] = img1

# extract base image and alpha channel from img1_pad
bgr = img1_pad[:,:,0:3]
alpha = img1_pad[:,:,3]
alpha = cv2.merge([alpha,alpha,alpha])

# combine bgr with img2 using alpha as mask
result = np.where(alpha==255, bgr, img2)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('face_blue_rect.png', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]